# How can I change the port of a Spring JaxWs proxy?

Tags: spring, jax-ws

I have a working web service client based on Spring, defined as:

```
<bean id="myService" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl"  value="classpath:/ex/MyService.wsdl" />
    <property name="namespaceUri"     value="http://ex.tld/namespace" />
    <property name="serviceName"      value="MyService" />
    <property name="portName"         value="MyServicePort01" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="ex.MyService" />
</bean>
```

I need to access the same service on a list of different endpoints. Since the list is dynamic I cannot simply configure several Spring JaxWsPortProxy beans for this.

Can I change the binding dynamically? How can I solve this while still leveraging Spring facilities for WS clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply changed the endpoint address of the proxy:

`((BindingProvider)myService).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://new/endpoint/address");`

As seen above, the proxy that Spring returns can be casted to a BindingProvider (like a normal JaxWs proxy).

If someone adopts this, beware of synchronization issues.

Answer (score 0):

I configured in xml, as you.
After, in postConsruct set endpoint, and call afterPropertiesSet:

```
 @Autowired
 private JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean myService;

 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
   myService.setEndpointAddress("http://new/endpoint/address");
   myService.afterPropertiesSet(); 
}
```